# Spring boot Restcontroller @RoleAllowed in the interface implementation is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have created an interface with a default method that defines the `@RequestMapping` and `@RoleAllowed` and implemented in one `Restcontroller`. But the `@RoleAllowed` property is not talking from the default method. PFB the code

```
public interface Resource{
@REquestMapping(value="/api/test",method=RequestMethod.GET)
@RoleAllowed({"READ_ONLY"})
default public String testEndPoint(){
  return "defaultmethod";
}

}

public class ResourceImpl implements Resource{

@override
public String testEndPoint(){
  return "ResourceImpl";
}
}

}
```

`@RoleAllowed` is not working in `ResourceImpl`. If I am not overriding `testEndPoint` method it is working fine

Comment: The `@RoleAllowed` isn't annotated with `@Inherited` so overriding will not have it added to the method in the impl. You will have to explicitly add it again. In theory using `@Secured` (from Spring Security instead of `@RoleAllowed` from JEE) should make it work as that is `@Inherited`.

Comment: Thanks It is working fine with @Secured